# How can I implement MergeSort using Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, merge, linked-list

How can I implement "MergeSort" using Linked List in Java using the implementation below?
Here's my implementation of Linked List:

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        tail = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(Object value) {
        tail = new Node(value);
        tail.setNext(tail);
    }

    public void purge() {
        tail = null;
    }

    public Object getFirst() {
        Node rigby = tail.getNext();
        return rigby.getValue();
    }

    public Object getLast() {
        return tail.getValue();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (tail == null);
    }

    public void assign(LinkedList list) {
        if (list.isEmpty())
            tail = null;
        else {
            this.append(list.tail.getNext().getValue());

            Node tmp = list.tail.getNext();
            while (tmp != list.tail) {
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
                this.append(tmp.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public void append(Object value) {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            tail = new Node(value);
            tail.setNext(tail);
        } else {
            Node tmp = new Node(value);
            tmp.setNext(tail.getNext());
            tail.setNext(tmp);
            tail = tmp;
        }
    }

    public void prepend(Object value) {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            tail = new Node(value);
            tail.setNext(tail);
        } else {
            Node tmp = new Node(value);
            tmp.setNext(tail.getNext());
            tail.setNext(tmp);
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(LinkedList list) {
        if (this != list) {
            // temp variables
            Node mordecai = tail.getNext();
            Node rigby = list.tail.getNext();
            // previouses
            Node prev = tail;
            Node prev2 = list.tail;
            while (true) {
                if (mordecai.getValue().getClass().getName() == "Node") {
                    if (!mordecai.getValue().equals(rigby.getValue()))
                        return false;
                } else {
                    if (!mordecai.getValue().toString().equals(rigby.getValue().toString()))
                        return false;
                }
                prev = mordecai;
                mordecai = mordecai.getNext();
                prev2 = rigby;
                rigby = rigby.getNext();

                if ((prev == tail) && (prev2 == list.tail))
                    return true;
                if ((prev == tail) || (prev2 == list.tail))
                    return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }


    public void extract(Object value) {
        if (!this.isEmpty()) {
            Node tmp = tail.getNext();
            Node prev = tail;
            while (true) {
                if (tmp.getValue().equals(value)) {
                    prev.setNext(tmp.getNext());
                    break;
                }
                prev = tmp;
                tmp = tmp.getNext();

                if (prev == tail)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String str = "";
            Node tmp = tail.getNext();
            str += tmp.getValue().toString();
            while (tmp != tail) {
                str += "  ->  ";
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
                str += tmp.getValue().toString();
            }
            return str;
        }
    }


    class Node {
        Object data;
        Node next;

        public Node(Object value) {
            data = value;
        }

        public Node(Object value, Node pointer) {
            data = value;
            next = pointer;
        }

        public Object getValue() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            data = value;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node pointer) {
            next = pointer;
        }

        public boolean equals(Node var) {
            if (next.equals(var.next)) {
                if (data.getClass().getName() == "Node") {
                    if (data.equals(var.data))
                        return true;
                } else {
                    if (data.toString().equals(var.data.toString()))
                        return false;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't make heads or tails and analyzing gave me migraine. I need help with this. I've searched and I only found an Array implementation.

Comment: One reason only a few crazy people try to write their own LinkedList when there is a standard working built in version. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort()` is a `merge sort` in java

```
 public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Java Doc

> The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance. The specified list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable. This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.

Answer (score 0):

You'll do better in your later coursework assignments if you worked from an abstract description of the solution ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort